# How to get header values in https calls in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created an API which gets a header value which it matches with the `apikey` from the web.config.

[image]

and the code to get the header value in the application is

```
  var authToken = Request.Headers.Where(t => t.Key == "apiKey").ToList();
```

It works perfectly when I work with HTTP but when I use HTTPS it doesn't get the header value.

[image]

As shown in the image `authToken.count = 0` which means it is not getting the header value.

The request object is of type `public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }`

Can someone please suggest me where I am making the mistake.

Comment: can you provide more details about version you are using , and The platform .Net fx or .Net Core

Comment: Sure @sayahimad  , I am using .net 4.7.2 and webapi 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve data from your Header You can use this `Request.Headers`, you will find an example below

`var apiKey = Request.Headers.GetValues("apiKey")`

**Resquest From Postman**

[image: Resquest From Postman]

**Retrieve your data from header**

[image: Retrieve your data from header]

Comment: thank you for your response but the above solution works for mvc application I guess not APi.   In the api it is giving error          "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type HttpRequestHeaders"

Comment: i'am using API , .Net Core :( .

Comment: @Simba i just update my post , i was thinking that you were using .Net Core .

Comment: Use `.TryGetValues` or else you will risk an `InvalidOperationException` if the header is not found.